# How can I include the original email in an Exchange auto-reply for shared-mailboxes?

Tags: exchange-server, auto, reply

Does anybody know if this is possible for a Shared-mailbox created in Exchange?

Can we make sure that the customer receives the email in the return reply that the customer has sent to us?
The customer now  "only" receive the auto-reply that we have created under auto-reply

So I want to setup the orginal email within the autoreply?

I tried using the Outlook settings from the OWA but I can't find any solution

Comment: Are you looking for a setting or code that can do that for you?

Comment: Both would work.. but i would prefer a setting..

Comment: I'd suggest posting non-programming questions to the https://www.superuser.com web site instead.